# Boost.Spirit parser does not match

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am having difficulty understanding why the following parser fails to parse `test`.
After the call to `qi::phrase_parse`, `result` is true, `it2` points at the end of the string, but `mynr` is still 0:

```
std::string test = "#define   SOMEMACRO 8.0";
  auto it2 = test.begin();
  auto endIt2 = test.end();
  double mynr = 0;
  bool result = 
    qi::phrase_parse(
      it2, 
      endIt2, 
      ("#define" >> (*qi::alnum) >> qi::double_[ref(mynr) = qi::_1]), 
      qi::space);
```

I am suspecting it has something to do with `qi::alnum` and space skipping.

I tried reducing my case to individual components. I verified these three parsers separately and found that:

- "#define" indeed consumes "#define"
- `(*qi::alnum)` is able to consume `SOMEMACRO`
- `qi::double_` is able to consume `8.0`

Separately, each parser works fine, however put together in the form above works oddly. Further small tests seemed to indicate to me `(*qi::alnum)` when used like I am using it seems to consume more than just `SOMEMACRO`, but the rest of the string also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updates actually made me realize what was going on. And you're correct, `*alnum` is eating more than you want.

```
("#define" >> lexeme[*qi::alnum] >> (qi::double_)[boost::phoenix::ref(mynr) = boost::spirit::_1])
```

This works.

`*alnum` is eating alphanumeric characters, and skipping spaces between them. So it actually ate `SOMEMACRO    8`. Then, when I suggested that it worked when eating `8.0` at the end, that was because the double parser consumed `.0`.

The new parser at the top requires that the `*alnum` have no spaces in the middle of it.

Here's the new things to note about the grammar:

1. I've included the semantic action to store the value of the double. It stores it in a double called `mynr`.
2. I've wrapped `*alnum` in a [`lexeme`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/lexeme.html). This causes the parser to not skip any characters while inside.
3. With this correct grammar, it's able to parse `"#define   SOMEMACRO 8.0"` and `"#define   SOMEMACRO 8"`

Comment: I tried it and it does indeed consume the whole string when having 8.0 instead. However I don't think it's parsing it as I am expecting. I have updated my question with my findings.

Comment: Your semantic action should be: `[boost::phoenix::ref(mynr) = boost::spirit::_1]`.

Comment: This parses correctly for me now, I missed that the *alnum was doing preskips as well.

Comment: What does it mean that it does preskips? Does it mean it uses the skip parameter in `parse_phrase` to skip what comes before an alnum char? Also, was this why `eps` was necessary? Because `eps` doesn't do preskips?

Comment: So, I've changed it up a bit more to simplify it. `lexeme` works better in this case than `no_skip`. I'll try to explain both though. In your original case, your grammar was the same as `*space >> #define >> *space >> *(*space >> alnum) >> *space >> double >> *space`. What we wanted to transform this to was `#define >> *space >> *alnum >> *space >> double >> *space. Note that the only difference is the `*alnum` area. Lexeme causes this change to happen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26738/discussion-between-sharth-and-zadirion)